# ListView with Checkboxes: How can I check if it's checked or not?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-arrayadapter

In my programm I have a simple `ListView` and set an `ArrayAdapter` on it:

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
R.layout.row_layout_checkbox, R.id.textView_checkbox, list);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

"list" is a String-Array(String[]).

Layout XML **row_layout_checkbox** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So my **question**: How can I check which checkboxes are checked or not so I can put true or false in an boolean-Array?

(It should can check the checkboxes of each item and should be multiple choice not single choice.)

Answer (score 0):

You should extend your own custom adapter from ArrayAdapter, to get what you want.

There is a bunch of good tutorials about doing this, like here:
[custom listview adapter tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial)

According to that, you can try something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean[] booleanArray;

    public MovieAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes ArrayList<String> list, boolean[] booleanArray) {
        super(context, 0 , list);
        mContext = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.booleanArray = booleanArray;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_checkbox,parent,false);
        }    
        String item = list.get(position);

        CheckBox checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_checkBox);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                booleanArray[position] = isChecked;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This should basically work. But I guess, en even better way would be, to create your own data model class, which contain the string for the TextView and the checked state of the checkbox. Then you extend your custom adapter from `ArrayAdapter<YourDataModel>` instead from `ArrayAdapter<String>`. (That's what's actually shown in the tutorial.)

Comment: What should be 'listItem'? I think it should be replaced with convertView?